# Haworth projection of Sucrose

Tags: carbohydrates

I was searching for the Haworth projection of sucrose and I got this image from wikipedia (and much of the internet).
(wikipedia link: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sucrose).[image]

But isn't it wrong!?
The image shows a (#1Carbon to #5C) linkage of glucose to fructose respectively.
What i think the image is showing:
(edited wikipedia image)
[image]

But it should show (#1C to #2C) linkage of glucose to fructose respectively.
Should it not be like this image:
[image]

Comment: Your fructose in the second picture is numbered incorrectly. #2 is #5 and #5 is #2. The correct C2 is a ketal carbon, a masked ketone. Fructose is a 2-ketose.

Comment: This may be of help: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/87178/identifying-the-d-l-form-of-any-aldose-or-ketose-in-cyclic-form/106929#106929

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are the same, just shown in a different conformation and a different view.

[image]

As user55119 points out in the comments, the numbering went awry (in fructose, #2 is the anomeric carbon in the ring form, or the carbonyl carbon in the linear form).

Sucrose has no reducing "ends", which it would have if fructose would link via the #5 carbon.

If you look at one of the [crystal structures of sucrose](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=SUCROS01&DatabaseToSearch=Published), you will find that the rings are not parallel but rather perpendicular, allowing some nice hydrogen bonds:

[image]

Comment: Beside the pure chemical perspective of this answer, it is an eye-catching showcase about advantages of vector-based images in formats like `.svg`.

Comment: @Buttonwood The provided figure was pixel-based, so I had to remove the background to make it transparent...

Comment: Great animation, much thanks. Which software did you use btw.

Comment: @KarstenTheis Oh, but it has so much similarity to the depiction of sucrose on top of the property box in the English edition of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sucrose), which is available as `.svg` [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Saccharose2.svg) ...

Comment: @JustCurious The first one may be achieved with [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) (though, by shape of the symbols, it does not necessarily look like the version in Linux). The second is exporting an animation from [Jmol](http://jmol.sourceforge.net/). In both cases, selection of a gif at rate/resolution/frames per second *suitable* enough to stay within the limit of approx 2 MB. For the former, let's see in the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59645368#59645368).

Comment: @JustCurious I used commercial software I happen to have, PowerPoint for the first figure, and Camtasia to capture the screen and turn it into an animated gif. The second figure is of SUCROS01 was rendered with the open software Jmol.